# JavaScript IF statement boolean strict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, boolean

I am setting a mode in a script by passing a "truthy" boolean to a function. In the function a simple `if` statement checks if the param is `true` or `false`. I sometimes pass it as a string or a bool which has always worked, but for some reason it isn't for this:

```
setMode: function(Setting) {    
    if (Setting) {
        console.log('Enabling mode');
    } else {
        console.log('Disabling mode');
    }
}
```

For example when I pass it a string `'false'` and log `Setting` to console, the console says `false`, yet the `if` statement thinks it's true.

I have to add this to the start of the function for it to work:

if (typeof Setting == 'string') {
    Setting = (Setting == "true");
}

An example of it in use:

```
var inverted = $('INPUT[name="Mode"]').prop('checked');
app.setMode(inverted);
```

and another:

```
var mode = localStorage.getItem('Mode');
this.setMode(mode);
```

It's so bizarre since I've done this type of thing for years yet it's only starting now. Maybe because I'm using `localStorage` and `.prop`?

Comment: `localStorage` can only store strings. I recommend access to LS to be always wrapped in JSON.parse/stringify pair.

Comment: Does it matter? An `if` statement will still see it as `true` or `false` if it's a string or a boolean, but it's not in this case.

Comment: Besides, I also tried using a checkbox with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to log `'false'` it is obvious that console logs `false`(it is a string) and that the if statement sees `true`, because a not-empty string is a true boolean value.

If you want to check if the string is `"true"` or `"false"` you have to do it with normal operators. So you could add this line at the beginning of your function:

```
Setting = (typeof Setting === 'string') ? Setting === "true" : Setting;
```

Comment: That won't work with the string 'false'. `!!'false' === true`

Comment: See my updated answer, empty strings are false, not-empty are true for JS.

Comment: How is `if (!!Setting)` different from `if (Setting)`, other than adding useless clutter?

Comment: It's different to log `Setting` or `!!Setting`, anyway you're right, in this case it changes nothing, the best way to do it is adding `if (typeof Setting == 'string') { Setting = (Setting == "true"); }`

Comment: Why should I need to force it to be a boolean? Shouldn't the `if` statement see it as `true` or `false` because it's _truthy_ or _falsy_?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about string to boolean conversions:

ECMA SPEC:

> The result [of this conversion] is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); 
>   otherwise the result is true.

So yes, if you pass the string "false" it will be converted to `true`, which means the only option you have is to manually check for the strings "true" or "false" and do the conversion by yourself.

However, the jQuery function `.prop("checked")` is supposed to return a boolean value (or `undefined` if the property is not defined). So I would say you should be able to actually do

```
if (elem.prop("checked"))
```

like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B6nkj/).

Answer (score 1):

> For example when I pass it a string `'false'` and log it to console, the console says `false`, yet the if statement thinks it's true.

The console output is confusing, it is concealing the quotes and logging `false` both for the string `"false"` and the boolean `false`. Yet, these two are not equivalent, the string is not empty and indeed truthy.

> Maybe because I'm using localStorage and .prop?

Yes. The `.checked` property returns a boolean and everything works well. In contrast, [local storage only stores strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17453613/1048572), and when you pass in a boolean you get back its stringification. You can undo that by using

```
var modeStr = localStorage.getItem('Mode');
var mode = JSON.parse(modeStr);
this.setMode(mode);
```